# Difference between 1x16 and 2x8 attacks in Angry Birds Epic

Tags: angry-birds-epic

In Angry Birds Epic, I noticed that enemies sometimes have the same damage, but in a different attack pattern. For example, the thug has one attack of 16 damage, and the bird catcher has two attacks of 8 damage.

What is the practical difference between these two?

When you apply the electric-barrier skill (all attacks deal a counter-attack), I thought maybe 2x8 attacks will result in two counter-attacks, but it still deals only 1x counter-attack damage.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  My shock shield reflects 3x for a 3x attack and deals tons of damage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't pay enough attention to this. Effects like shock shield reflect, as is mentioned in the description, *once per attack.* So effectively, monsters with more attacks are susceptible to greater retaliatory effects.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have an example with Prince Porky. His dodge, allows to ignore (old versions), about... 130 damage. If you deal 140 damage, he will dodge it, but if you deal 70 damage two times, he will not dodge that, because 70 doesn't surpass 130, and 70*2 is 140, but he doesn't actually receive 70, only receives the half amount twice.